# How to implement the parent :: __ construct () call in the php extension ？

Tags: php, php-extension

**I want to implement the following code in the php extension**

```
class A{
    public function __construct(){
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**I have written these：**

```
 zend_class_entry *a_class_ce, *b_class_ce;

    ZEND_METHOD(a_class, __construct){
    }

    ZEND_METHOD(b_class, __construct){
    }

    static zend_function_entry a_class_method[]={
            ZEND_ME(a_class, __construct, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
            {NULL, NULL, NULL}
    };

    static zend_function_entry b_class_method[]={
            ZEND_ME(b_class, __construct, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
            {NULL, NULL, NULL}
    };

    ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION(test){
        zend_class_entry a_ce, b_ce;

        INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(a_ce, "A", a_class_method);
        a_class_ce = zend_register_internal_class(&a_ce TSRMLS_CC);

        INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(b_ce, "B", b_class_method);
        b_class_ce = zend_register_internal_class_ex(&b_ce, b_class_ce TSRMLS_CC);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**But I do not know how to implement parent :: __ construct ();**

**How to achieve parent :: __ construct () ？**

Comment: @Luke I am not a PHP guru but umm... no, IMO this doesn't have *anything to do with the Zend framework*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks, I'm way off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this exactly, but it seems like it'd work based on usage I've seen in some of the core extensions in `php-src`:

```
void call_parent_constructor(zval* zobj)
{
    zend_class_entry* ce = zend_get_class_entry(zobj);
    zend_class_entry* parentEntry = ce->parent;

    if (parentEntry == NULL) {
        php_error(E_ERROR,"fail call_parent_constructor(): class has no parent");
        return;
    }

    zend_call_method(
        &zobj,
        parentEntry,
        &parentEntry->constructor,
        "__construct",
        sizeof("__construct")-1,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL);
}
```

This example assumes you need to pass no parameters to the parent constructor. If you need to pass parameters then note that `zend_call_method()` limits you to passing 0, 1 or 2 parameters only.

**Update** I have tested this approach in PHP 5 and it works as expected.